# Inheriting a constructor in a .h and .cpp file

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

So I've got two classes: Object and Player.
I want Player to inherit from Object because Object has basic functions that I need.
Player has it's added-on functions that expand from what Object can do.
I have four files:
Object.cpp, Object.h, Player.cpp, and Player.h.

To make an example out of my situation, I have added a variable to my Player class:
playerVariable. My Object constructor parameters does not contain this, however my Player constructor does, so you can see that Player expands Object.

Anyways, Here is my code:

Object.h:

```
#include <hge.h>
#include <hgesprite.h>
#include <hgeanim.h>
#include <math.h>

class Object{
int x, y;
HTEXTURE tex;
hgeAnimation *anim;
float angle, FPS, velocity;

public:
    Object(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS);
    //Setters
    void SetX(int x);
    void SetY(int y);
    void SetSpeed(int FPS); //Image Speed
    void SetAngle(float angle); //Image Angle
    void SetVelocity(float velocity); //Object Speed/Velocity
    //Getters
};
```

Object.cpp:

```
/*
** Object
** 
*/
#include <hge.h>
#include <hgesprite.h>
#include <hgeanim.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Object.h"

Object::Object(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->tex = tex;
    this->FPS = FPS;
}
//Setters
void Object::SetX(int x){
    this->x = x;
}

void Object::SetY(int y){
    this->x = x;
}

void Object::SetSpeed(int FPS){
    this->FPS = FPS;
    anim->SetSpeed(FPS);
}

void Object::SetAngle(float angle){
    this->angle = angle;
}

void Object::SetVelocity(float velocity){
    this->velocity = velocity;
}

//Getters
```

Player.h:

```
#include <hge.h>
#include <hgesprite.h>
#include <hgeanim.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Object.h"

class Player : public Object{
    int playerVariable;

public:
    Player(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS, int playerVariable);
    //Setters
    void SetX(int x);
    void SetY(int y);
    void SetSpeed(int FPS); //Image Speed
    void SetAngle(float angle); //Image Angle
    void SetVelocity(float velocity); //Object Speed/Velocity
    //Getters
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
/*
** Object
** 
*/
#include <hge.h>
#include <hgesprite.h>
#include <hgeanim.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Object.h"
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS, playerVariable){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->tex = tex;
    this->FPS = FPS;
}
//Setters
void Object::SetX(int x){
    this->x = x;
}

void Object::SetY(int y){
    this->x = x;
}

void Object::SetSpeed(int FPS){
    this->FPS = FPS;
    anim->SetSpeed(FPS);
}

void Object::SetAngle(float angle){
    this->angle = angle;
}

void Object::SetVelocity(float velocity){
    this->velocity = velocity;
}

//Getters
```

My problem is, I'm not exactly sure if I'm setting this up right.
I've looked at tutorials on inheritance but I have no idea how to set it up with both
a .h file and a .cpp file for the classes. Can someone help?

Comment: State your actual problem, and post some (minimal) code that ilustrates your problem.

Comment: Everything in the .cpp should just refer to Player. You only need to mention the base class in the declration of player

Answer (score 3):

You are defining the `Object` functionality twice. You don't need to define that, it will be inherited from `Object` and automatically be available on `Player`.

Your `Player` constructor needs to invoke the base `Object` constructor. This is done with constructor initialization lists:

```
Player::Player(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS, playerVariable)
   : Object(x, y, tex, FPS) // forward arguments to base constructor
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the base class constructor this way, specifying every parameter :

```
Player::Player(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS, playerVariable): Object(x, y, tex, FPS) {
```

Comment: Well now what am I doing wrong?


http://pastebin.com/zN60ce2T


I have invoked the base class constructor..

Object.h:


http://pastebin.com/zN60ce2T

Object.cpp:

http://pastebin.com/mJdLSM6e


Player.h:


http://pastebin.com/fhDtGfb2


Player.cpp:



http://pastebin.com/fhDtGfb2

Comment: Object.h and Player.cpp links are wrong. Update your original question instead of posting pastebin links.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't actually need class `Player` to override `SetX(int)`, `SetY(int)`, `SetSpeed(int)`, `SetAngle(float)`, and `SetVelocity(float)` of `Object`. If you did, then you would make these `Object` member functions `virtual`.

A few other notes:

1. You don't need to redefine the `Object` member functions in `Player.cpp`. `Player` is an `Object`, so it inherits the member functions of class `Object`. Also, if there are any differences between the implementation in `Object.cpp` and `Player.cpp` then you will get linker errors due to a violation of the One Definition Rule.
2. The `Object` destructor should be declared `virtual`.
3. Rather than setting the members of `Object` directly in the `Player` constructor, you could use an initialization list:

   ```
   Player::Player(int x, int y, HTEXTURE tex, float FPS, playerVariable)
       : Object(x, y, tex, FPS), playerVariable(playerVariable)
   {
   }
   ```

   Using initialization lists is much more efficient. It is even necessary in this case because `Object::x`, `Object::y`, `Object::tex`, and `Object::FPS` are all private to `Object` and friends.
4. In `Object`, you should provide a custom copy constructor and copy-assign operator overload (`Object::operator=(const Object&)`). The C++ compiler provides default implementations of these member functions for you, but because you have pointer members and `HTEXTURE` members, you likely need to provide explicit implementations to handle the deep copy. The copy constructor and copy-assign overload must always make deep copies.
5. There is a mismatch on the type of `FPS`. The `Object::FPS` member is declared as a `float`, but the parameter to `Object::SetSpeed(int)` is an `int`.